# Should I create a Scalar/Number class for preventing floating point errors?

Tags: javascript, performance, floating-point, game-physics

I'm writing a physics engine in JavaScript, but I got many problems with floating point errors. I found a solution for it, but don't know if I should use it.
My idea was to make a Scalar class like this:

```
function Scalar(value){
    this.value = Math.round(value * 1000000)/1000000;
}
Scalar.prototype.add = function(another){
    // Scalar class rounds the values so no floating point errors occur
    return new Scalar(this.value + another.value);
}
// sub, div, mul, ...
```

Every time it does an operation, it rounds the value to a less accurate value, preventing a floating point error. This would speed up programming for me, but would this be a good solution, even when performance is a problem too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Scalar class will give much less precise results than the normal implementation of Javascript numbers. You say "preventing floating point rounding error" but it increases the floating point rounding error in most cases, and will destroy small numbers. For example, the Planck constant is 6.62607004 × 10<sup>-34</sup> m<sup>2</sup> kg / s. What happens when you try to store that in your type?

The underlying representation of Javascript numbers, IEEE 754 64-bit binary floating point, gives results with errors around one part in 2<sup>53</sup>, or about one part in 10<sup>15.9</sup>. You are unlikely to be dealing with inputs that have been measured to anything like that precision. It does so across a range of magnitudes from about 10<sup>-308</sup> to 10<sup>308</sup>. That is a wide enough range to be able to store the mass in grams of a proton and the mass in grams of the observable universe.

Its most significant limitation is in situations in which fractions with exact terminating decimal expansions, such as money in dollars and cents, have special significance. Those fractions have no special significance in physics.

It really is a very, very good data type for physics calculations.

Comment: I was afraid of it. Fractions have impact on performance, so I'm not going to use them. I already had a 'plan-B' to make an object with functions like `equals`, `lessThan` or `moreThan`, which will catch floating point errors with some threshold (e.g. 0.00000001 equals 0).

Comment: @E730 That's not a good idea either. Two things you need to learn to do: (1) properly write FP code to keep error down, and (2) write FP code in a way which is resilient to error. (Using "some threshold" is amost always the wrong way to do that, BTW.)

Comment: @E730 I just told you that the simplest, easiest to use, numerical type in Javascript is an excellent choice for most physics calculations. Why are you "afraid" of that? I suggest posting a new question giving an example of where you think floating point rounding error is adversely affecting your physics calculations, and asking what to do about it.

Comment: @E730 A fixed threshold, regardless of the magnitude of the numbers being compared, is particularly bad. Under the comparison rule you are considering, Planck's constant is equal to zero. So is the mass in grams of a proton. Either would have really big implications for physics.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I was afraid of the fact that my Scalar class was a bad idea. Your'e right, but constants like proton mass and planck's constant don't play a role in a game physics engine :)